# Conditional outputs on data sources in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a sql server terraform module that outputs the name of a sql server for the databases to get created in. However, some environments should use an external server outside of the terraform project instead. Most datacenters we have do not have this external server, just a few.

I've set up the external server using data sources as usual, and made both the output, normal server and datasource conditional on a variable thats passed in like this:

```
variable "use_external_sql_server" {
  type = bool
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sqlserver" {
  count = var.use_external_sql_server ? 0 : 1
  name = "sql-interal-sql_server"
  ....
}

data "azurerm_mssql_server" "external_sql_server" {
  count = var.use_external_sql_server ? 1 : 0
  name                = "sql-${var.env}-${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "rg-${var.env}-${var.location}"
}

output "sql_server_name" {
    value = var.use_external_sql_server ? data.azurerm_mssql_server.external_sql_server.name : azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver[0].name
    depends_on = [
      azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver,
      data.azurerm_mssql_server.external_sql_server
    ]
}
```

However, I'm running into issues with the output. It requires data.azurerm_mssql_server.external_sql_server to exist to evaulate the condition, even if "use_external_server" is false. This is not ideal as I have to manual create dummy servers to fix this condition, so that that conditional can evaulate to true.

Is there a way to do this conditional without having to have "data.azurerm_mssql_server.external_sql_server" actually exist?

Comment: For one, I think there is an error in your output anyway because the data source is created with the `count` argument so it would have to have an index. Secondly, I would probably use `try` built in function, something like `value = var.use_external_sql_server? try(data.azurerm_mssql_server.external_sql_server[0].name, null) : azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver[0].name`. I don't think you need `depends_on` as well.

Comment: yeah try is the solution here https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/try. It will evaluate each expression and return the first that doesnt produce an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get rid of the conditional in the output and just use a [try](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/try).

> try evaluates all of its argument expressions in turn and returns the result of the first one that does not produce any errors.
> This is a special function that is able to catch errors produced when evaluating its arguments, which is particularly useful when working with complex data structures whose shape is not well-known at implementation time.

You could then possibly write something like

```
output "sql_server_name" {
    value = try(data.azurerm_mssql_server.external_sql_server[0].name, azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver[0].name, "")
    depends_on = [
      azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver,
      data.azurerm_mssql_server.external_sql_server
    ]
}
```